# How to get user info from email in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, bcrypt

I am using bcryptjs and nodejs along with firebase, and facing problem in login.
The userinfo (along with hashed password) is getting stored in firebase database (sign-up is working fine), to compare the entered password (by user) with stored password, I am using below method -

```
bcrypt.compare(req.user.password, user.password, function(err, res) {
   // res === true
});
```

ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

I need userinfo from the entered emailid, but I am stuck here, couldn't retrieve userinfo from firebase as userinfo is mapped to uid, not email.

Can I get userinfo from user entered email id (from firebase), or some other way to authenticate user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged with `node.js`: in a trusted environment you can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) to [look up users by their email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data):

> ```
> admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
>   .then(function(userRecord) {
>     // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
>     console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
>   })
>   .catch(function(error) {
>     console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
>   });
> ```